# Overriding SoapClient doRequest returns a string, not an object

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I'm overriding the doRequest function in SoapClient, in order to parse/decode the response. The requests get sent fine, the content of the response is fine. The problem I'm getting is the second function (__myDoRequest) is returning a string, not an object.

I suspect since myDoRequest bypasses __call, then __call must be formatting the response in some way. I can't (to my knowledge) override __call as it's expecting the function name and arguments, which I don't know in the case of myDoRequest (I'm just regenerating the headers, and copying xml into the body). Is there any solution that does **not** involve parsing the xml document to get the function / arguments?

Things to note:

`$this->parse_response($response)`: returns a string

In short:

`$this->soapclient->__doRequest(...);`: returns string

`$this->soapclient->name_of_search($request)`: returns object(stdClass)

I want `$this->soapclient->name_of_search($request)` to return an object, not a string.

__call

```
public function __call($function_name, $arguments)
{
    $this->__setSoapHeaders($this->generateWSSecurityHeader());
    return parent::__call($function_name, $arguments);
}
```

__doRequest

```
public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0) 
{           
    $response = parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way);

    return $this->parse_response($response);    
}
```

__myDoRequest

```
function __myDoRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0) 
{
    //Set up the new headers
    $xml = '<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="..." xmlns:ns2="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">        
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>';
    $xml .= $this->generateWSSecurityHeader("xml");
    $xml .= "</SOAP-ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:Body>";
    $xml .= $request;
    $xml .= "</SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";

    $response = parent::__doRequest($xml, $location, $action, $version, $one_way);

    if((isset($this->__soap_fault)) && ($this->__soap_fault != null)) 
    { 
        $exception = $this->__soap_fault; 

        if($exception != null) 
        { 
            throw $exception; 
        } 
    } 
    return $this->parse_response($response);
}
```

How they're getting called:

```
<snip>
if($raw_xml)
{
    $response = $this->soapclient->__doRequest($raw_xml, '...', "", 1, 0);
}
else
{
    $response = $this->soapclient->name_of_search($request);
}
<snip>
```